# onOptionsItemSelected is called twice?

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

i have this problem which i never expect it to occur. When i pressed on the Menu button, the program display the Menu and after i click on one of the items from the Menu, it pops out a item list for me to choose. However, just when the item list pops out, some of the code in onOptionsItemSelected() was called when i did not even select any item. After i selected on of the items, onOptionsItemSelected() got called again (i know this is called because an item was selected). Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem or even why is this happening? Below is the coding...

Btw, the 'count' is just an integer variable to show whether onOptionsItemSelected() was called as it would increment each time when called.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    SubMenu sendMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Change Profile");

    int size = profileNames.size();

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        sendMenu.add(0,i,0,profileNames.get(i).toString());
    }

    menu.add(1, size, 0, "Configuration");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}




@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    count++;

    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(this, "Count: "+count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast1.show();

    selectedProfileName = null;
    //change the map according to the selected profile name
    if(item.getItemId()<=profileNames.size()-1){
        selectedProfileName = profileNames.get(item.getItemId());
        setContentView(new SampleView(this));
    }
    else{
        Intent myIntent=new Intent(this,configurationTabWidget.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    //just to re-draw the map with the new selected profile name        
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting two items - first you select the "Change Profile" menu item, and then you select the particular item from the SubMenu.

Comment: i thought i am just adding a submenu to the Menu?

Comment: Change your toast to show the menu item clicked too, something "Count: " + count + ", item: " + item.getTitle().  When I did this to your code, it showed that first I Clicked on "Change Profile" and then "aaa" (the name of the profile in my list of profiles).

Comment: Perhaps you could add an if statement to ensure it's one of the submenu items instead of the "ChangeProfile" item.